# Most efficient way to move multiple rows at a time

Tags: php, mysql

This is a short term solution to a long term problem...

I have a database created by someone else (isn't that always the case).  One particular table stores historical transactional data.  When this table becomes large, the site performs like crap.  When I can get to it, I will redesign database 3nf.  Until then, I need to limit the table to around 500,000 rows.  So I want to periodically run a script to move the oldest rows to an archive table that will probably never be used.  Let's say I am moving 5-10K rows at a time, what is the most efficient way to do it?

This is a MYSQL database.

Off the top of my head, I figure I will get a count of the number of rows.  Find out what the count - 500000 LIMIT 1 id is and move everything with and ID <= to that.

Do I just select, insert and delete or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Can you post the stated code? so we can improve what you are already using

Comment: Is the table indexed? Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724824/move-rows-from-tablea-into-table-archive

Comment: have you tried optimizing the table?  'optimize table MY_TABLE_NAME'

Comment: Yeah 500K rows is not a big table.  Ti seems to me the queries against it can be optimized or the tables can be indexed better.  Please post table info and problematic query(ies) for review. How many rows doe this table add on a daily basis?

Comment: I found this from a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939364/is-it-possible-to-move-a-record-from-one-table-to-another-using-a-single-sql-sta

Comment: This database is a joke.  Nothing is indexed.  It needs a massive overhaul.  2-4 million records are added to this table a day.  Their current workaround is to rename the table and create a new one to get the site back up.  There are no foreign keys.  The literal user name is in every table, etc...  I need a lot of time to straighten things out because of the cascade of changes.  They are a little company that exploded overnight.  I just need to know if select, insert and delete is the best way to move records to I can keep the table size down or if there is a better/different way to do it?

Comment: The trigger by Rujikin looks interesting.  That would probably provide respectable performance.